# Tensorflow 2 altered behaviour by package install

Tags: python

Does anyone know why you would get different behavior between a pip vs an anaconda install of TensorFlow 2.0.0?

```
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

print(f'TENSOR FLOW VERSION: {tf.__version__}\n')

model = load_model('path_to_model/mod_1626092802.2582898.h5')

img_dim = 128

def predict_img(img_abs):
    img_array = cv2.imread(img_abs)
    img_array = img_array/255.0

    tmp = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_dim, img_dim))
    tmp = tmp.reshape(1,img_dim, img_dim, 3).astype('float')

    # predict class
    prediction = model.predict(tmp)[0][0]
    return prediction

img_abs =  'path_to_img/img_1.jpg'

p = predict_img(img_abs)
p
```

Running the above with Tensorflow 2.0.0 installed via pip gives
p = 0.42

Running the above with Tensorflow 2.0.0 installed via anaconda gives
p = 0.47

Python versions are respectively:

- Python version: 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) \n[GCC 8.4.0]
- Python version: 3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 30 2019,
  19:07:31) \n[GCC 7.3.0]

Answer (score 0):

Apologies

It appears I had a discrepancy in cv2 versions between my conda and pip environments that lead to the issue.

After updating cv2 the issue was resolved.